# Unable to download word docx using PHPWord TemplateProcessor

Tags: php, phpword

I can generate download a word document generated from scratch using PHPWord:
Create the PhpWord object:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
```

add sections and rows (ommitted) and create the header:

```
$datetime = date('Y_M_d_G_i');
$filename = 'receipt_' . $datetime . '.docx';
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
```

create a writer out of the phpWord object:

```
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
```

write to output:

```
$xmlWriter->save("php://output");
```

What I have failed to do is download a document from a template on the server:
Creating the TemplateProcessor works: No errors and PHP recognizes $templateProcessor as an object of that class:

```
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(asset_url() . 'templates/receipt_template.docx');
```

But I cannot work out how to write to output. If I could generate a PhpWord object then I could use the IOFactory:: createWriter method, but TemplateProcessor does not have methods that return a PhpWord object.

The closest I can get is to attempt to create a $phpWord document out of the IOFactory::load.  But this just creates a blank document

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($templateProcessor->save());
```

Comment: From a quick peek into the TemplateProcessor it looks like it doesn't offer anything to be used for that. An easy workaround solution would be to just store the file after modifications with the template processor and loading the file with the IOFactory load and then serving that (+ unlinking the file after this if it's not needed in server)

Comment: That is the approach I decided to take: I use the TemplateProcessor->saveAs() method to save it to a directory. Then I use a codeigniter-specific command to force download the file. Each time I enter the controller I delete any previously saved files.

Answer (score 9):

```
<?
require_once "../include/PHPWord-develop/bootstrap.php";

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('contrato01.docx');

$templateProcessor->setValue('variable01', 'Sun');
$templateProcessor->setValue('variable02', 'Mercury');

//#####################################################
// Save File
//#####################################################
//#####################################################
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='ejemplo.docx'");
  $templateProcessor->saveAs('php://output');
//#####################################################
//#####################################################
?>
```

Comment: absolute legend!!